# Intuition behind recurrences with growth O(n log n) vs O(n²)

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

Been trying to get the intuition behind *why* two very similar recurrence relations don't follow a pattern I would expect. They are pretty well known relations:

Relation 1 -

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n$

Relation 2 -

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2$

When sketching out a tree for the first recurrence, the way I was taught to think that at every level of a tree, you are doing some amount of work.

```
Height 1 - do some O(n) of work
Height 2 - do some O(n) of work
Height log(n) - do some O(n) of work
```

Now In my head, If i visualize the work as a sum of all the work done, it seems like its $O(n\log(n))$ of work being done, which according to the master theorem is correct.

However, using the same intuition for the second recurrence is *wrong* as we know the master theorem tells us the answer is $O(n^2)$.

Any reason why the intuition seems to be correct for the first recurrence, and why it is wrong for the second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is the big O constants. In the first case, at successive heights you are doing work of $$n, 2\frac{n}{2}, 4\frac{n}{4}, \ldots = n,n,n,\ldots. $$ In the second case, at successive heights you are doing work of $$n^2,2\frac{n^2}{4}, 4\frac{n^2}{16}, \ldots = n^2,\frac{n^2}{2},\frac{n^2}{4}.$$ Since the series $1,1/2,1/4,\ldots$ converges, the total work is only $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Ah, so in this case, those constants are important. Very good reminder :) Thanks!

Comment: @C.B. The specific values are not, the fact that they are *squared* is.